# Замена символов в массиве JS

Tags: javascript

Есть два массива, например: `['i','b']` и `['и','б']`

Нужно символы из первого массива заменить символами из второго массива. Точнее, чтобы `i = и` и т.д.

Пример:

```
var firstArray = ['d','e','v','e','l','o','p','e','r'];
var secondArray = ['д','е','в','е','л','о','п','е','р'];
```

Нужно, чтобы `thirdArray` заменил значения `firstArray` из `secondArray`. В итоге, `thirdArray` должен быть равен `['д','е','в','е','л','о','п','е','р']`

Я пытался сделать как-то `replace`, но не получилось. Поэтому пишу сюда

Comment: не понятно суть вопроса, ну тогда возьмите сразу второй массив, или сделайте просто `firstArray  = secondArray`, Мне кажется вы не правильно сформулировали вопрос.

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan скорее всего у него `thirdArray` а-ля `['h','e','l','l','o','w','o','r','l','d']`, а первый и второй массивы представляют из себя соответствие ru-en. Но это лишь догадка)

Comment: @АлексейШ будем ждать гадалку))))

Comment: мне нужно изменить символы из 1 массива символами из 2 массива. Например, если в первом массиве есть символ "s", то нужно заменить его символом из второго массива " :) "

Answer (score 1):

```js
const ru = ['а', 'б', 'в', 'г', 'д'];
const en = ['a', 'b', 'v', 'g', 'd'];

const transliterateArray = arr => arr.map(letter => ru.indexOf(letter) >= 0 ? en[ru.indexOf(letter)] : letter);
const transliterateString = str => transliterateArray(str.split('')).join('');

const array = transliterateArray(['д', 'б', 'г']);
const string = transliterateString('ваб')

console.log(array)
console.log(string);
```